# Automating a series of manual steps

Tags: java, automation, scheduled-tasks, build-automation, job-scheduling

I need to automate a series of steps which include running a script and then deployment. The script is already written. The script merges the new values added to a table on server to some JSON files. These JSON files are config files, containing data.

So as soon as these the table is updated, I need to trigger the updation in these json files.

Can someone suggest me way to do it. I got to know of Distributed Job Scheduler. Is this a good option, or any other options are there. I am new to all these.

Please suggest all possible ways.

Explaination in brief:

As soon as values are updated in tables, I want a mechanism which is triggered, and the updated values are added to JSON files(files containing data in json format).

Note: I already have a script wriiten which merge the values from table to these files. I just need to trigger the script

Comment: "I need to trigger the updation in these ion files" - not sure what you meant here...

Comment: I meant as soon as values are updated in tables, I want a mechanism which is triggered, and the updated values are added to JSON files(files containing data in json format). Note: I already have a script wriiten which merge the values from table to these files.  I just need to trigger the script.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a job scheduler, but not necessarily a distributed one!

If your task is really simple you can schedule a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job, but if you want a to be able to have more configuration options, a very popular tool is [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I'm thinking if it's possible for you to put those

> JSON files are config files, containing data

under a [Version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). Having this will help you with both the updates you need and the triggering on newer version. The [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) servers are designed to solve exactly such cases. Since you've tagged JAVA and Jenkins was already suggested, other options are [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). You can chain the scripts as Build steps.

e.g.

```
Step[N]: check JSON files version (new version return 0, same return 1)
Step[N+1]: on success Step[N], run script to update JSON files
```